# Twilio - How do I get a list of the channels the user belongs to?

Tags: twilio

I am looking through the API and see https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/channels#list-all-channels:

But it seems inefficient if for every user, I have to get a list of every channel that exists, then filter by the ones they are members of.

Am I missing something here? Am I just supposed to store the SIDs of the channels the user belongs to in my own database or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation when you query the channels list you are doing it as the User. So they will only have access to the channels that they can see.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/channels#get-a-list-of-channels

Comment: Hmm, thanks. It seems like the JavaScript SDK and the REST API do different things. The REST API you just provide your Twilio credentials (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest#authentication) and it just gives you all the channels. The JavaScript SDK you need to request a token for that user (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/identity#server-create-an-access-token), then use the Messaging. Didn't realize that.